# Draw an X through a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a line through Figure 2? I was thinking of trying to draw two lines that cross the figure out, but don't know how I can identify the 4 corners of the figure to do that

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,14pt, letterpaper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, tikz, multicol}

\newcommand{\pythagwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\pythagheight}{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\draw 
  (A) -- 
  node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
  node[right] {?} (C) -- 
  node[below] {?} 
  (A);
\draw 
  (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \scalebox{1.4}{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\draw 
  (A) -- 
  node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
  node[right] {?} (C) -- 
  node[below] {?} 
  (A);
\draw 
  (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `current bounding box` node for that.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,14pt, letterpaper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, tikz, multicol}

\newcommand{\pythagwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\pythagheight}{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\draw 
  (A) -- 
  node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
  node[right] {?} (C) -- 
  node[below] {?} 
  (A);
\draw 
  (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \scalebox{1.4}{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\draw 
  (A) -- 
  node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
  node[right] {?} (C) -- 
  node[below] {?} 
  (A);
\draw 
  (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
  \draw[red,thick] (current bounding box.north west)
  -- (current bounding box.south east)
  (current bounding box.north east)
  -- (current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to define a `local bounding box`, which I combine here with the `caption` package in such a way that makes it easier to relatively position the figures and the captions. In the current picture, that is not too relevant, but it will be once you start drawing two pictures of different sizes.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,14pt, letterpaper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {?} (C) -- 
   node[below] {?} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (L.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption.}};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=R]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {?} (C) -- 
   node[below] {?} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
 \path (L) -- (R) node[midway,scale=1.4]{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$};
 \draw[red,thick] (R.north west)  -- (R.south east)
  (R.north east)  -- (R.south west);
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (R.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption.}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general a `local bounding box` will allow you to cross out whatever it contains.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Replace drawing transparent rectangle and red lines by a cross out node: `\node[cross out, fit=(current bounding box), draw=red, thick] {};`

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks for the suggestion! But loading `fit` and `shapes.misc` for only that may be a bit too much (unless you argue that one should then abandon the local bounding box stuff and just use `\node[cross out, fit=(A)(B)(C), draw=red, thick] {};` if one only wants to cross out the triangle but not the labels).